# How to add my token to external exchange

Tags: erc-20

I am planning to launch one ICO and before that I am checking how to list my coin in external exchange?
If anybody knows please help here 
What are the mandatory things I have to consider

Comment: Binance listing fee is up to one million US dollars.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the exchange, but etherdelta is a good place to start.

https://github.com/etherdelta/etherdelta.github.io/issues/199